# How is a variable sweep wing constructed?

Tags: aircraft-design, wing-sweep

How is a variable sweep wing able to change its sweep?

Comment: This is a pretty broad topic covering both aerodynamics and structural mechanics.

Comment: I edited the question to focus on what seems to be the main question, feel free to correct it or roll back if this isn't right. We already have a [question on the aerodynamic aspects](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/1726/1696) so a question on the structural aspects seems to be a good complement.

Comment: I vote to reopen as edited by fooot

Comment: It's about a [huge hinge](http://i.stack.imgur.com/vTkky.jpg) (source: [This question](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/19130/what-are-the-advantages-and-disadvantages-of-an-oblique-wing-over-a-swing-wing)).

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to sweep a wing is an [oblique flying wing](http://www.desktop.aero/library/whitepaper/). This is essentially a straight wing with pivoting rudders and engine pylons which flies at an increasing angle of sideslip where a swing wing aircraft would fold its wings back.

[image: oblique flying wing]

Oblique flying wing (picture [source](http://www.desktop.aero/library/whitepaper/owtestbed.jpg))

If you want to know more, I suggest to read [this website](http://www.desktop.aero/library/whitepaper/). Excerpt:

> Although the oblique flying wing concept was described by Jones in
>   1958 and a drawing by G. H. Lee was published in 1962, the concept
>   received little attention until the 1990's when active digital flight
>   control systems became more capable and widespread. The oblique
>   all-wing configuration was studied in detail by researchers at NASA,
>   Stanford University, McDonnell-Douglas, and Boeing in the 1990's as
>   part of a NASA program.

If the wing is attached to a fuselage, only the wing should move. Again, this can be achieved by pivoting a straight wing, as done in the NASA AD-1 research aircraft, or by folding the wings back with a huge hinge at the wing root, as done on [swing wing aircraft](https://www.flightglobal.com/news/articles/kings-of-the-swingers-top-13-swing-wing-aircraft-404176/).

[image: NASA AD-1 in flight]

NASA AD-1 in flight (picture [source](http://www.dfrc.nasa.gov/Gallery/Photo/AD-1/Large/EC81-14632.jpg))

The first aircraft with a variable wing sweep was the [Messerschmitt P-1101](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Messerschmitt_P.1101) which was almost completed in 1945 when WW II ended. It was supposed to fly as a fighter-bomber with reduced wing sweep and as a pure fighter with increased wing sweep, and sweep could only be changed on the ground. On the basis of this design Bell built the X-5 research aircraft, the first to change sweep in flight.

[image: P-1101 under construction]

P-1101 under construction (picture [source](http://www.airwar.ru/image/idop/fww2/p1101/p1101-1.jpg))

The mechanics of a swing wing is rather straightforward: All you need is a big hinge connecting the wing spar at the root and a big hydraulic cylinder or spindle drive for adjusting the wing's sweep angle. And a flexible fairing at the wing root. And something to compensate for the shifting aerodynamic center.

[image: Swing wing mechanism of the F-14]

Swing wing mechanism of the F-14 (picture [source](http://www.topedge.com/panels/aircraft/sites/mats/f14-detail-wsm-01.gif))