# What are the differences between an oblique wing and a swing wing?

Tags: aircraft-design, aerodynamics, drag

How they differ from each other.
How do they work.
What is the structural differences.
How do they help in reaching mach speeds and get better fuel efficiency.
How does they both perform with max level of technology.and other such differences.

Comment: Does [this](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/19130/what-are-the-advantages-and-disadvantages-of-an-oblique-wing-over-a-swing-wing) answer your question?